# Probabilities with unfair dice.

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

According to  $f(k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ and because $p = \frac16$ for each die we calculate the probability of two sixes with three dice thrown $f(2)=3\frac16^2(1-\frac16)=\frac1{12}\frac5{6}=\frac5{72}$.

Right now I'm facing an unfair dice problem, e. g. the probabilities of the dice for a six would be $p_1=\frac16,\quad p_2=\frac2{11},\quad p_3=\frac3{20}$.

How do we now calculate the probability of two sixes, suspecting that $p = p_1p_2p_3$ would not be the right solution?

Probably we have to calculate $p$ differently or use a nested equation like $f(k)=f_1(k)f_2(k)f_3(k)$? So far my ideas.

Comment: just compute each case and add, there aren't very many.

Comment: The probability that all three dice show a six is $p_1p_2p_3$.  The probability that specifically the first and second show a six while the third does not is $p_1p_2(1-p_3)$.  Similarly you can find the probability that specifically the first and third show a six but the second does not and so on...

Comment: Ahh, because $p_{fair}=3\frac16\frac16(1-\frac16)=\operatorname{B}(3,\frac16)$ I just have to add the three cases, ok got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: And, more general, can we somehow express this with the Bernoulli equation $f(k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ with $n$ unfair dice w/ probabilities $p_1,\dots, p_n$ and $k$ sixes?